# Dropdown menu in Quarto

Tags: r, drop-down-menu, quarto

I would like to create a dropdown menu in `Quarto` to show multiple plots. In `R Markdown` is this really simple using `# Dropdown menu {.tabset .tabset-dropdown}` with some `##` for each plot. Here is a reproducible example in R markdown:

````
---
title: "Dropdown menu in Rmarkdown"
date: "2022-08-29"
output: html_document
---

# Dropdown menu {.tabset .tabset-dropdown}

## Plot 1

```{r, echo=FALSE}
plot(1:10, 10:1)
```

## Plot 2

```{r, echo=FALSE}
hist(rnorm(100))
```

## Plot 3 

```{r, echo=FALSE}
plot(rnorm(10), rnorm(10))
```
````

Output:

[image]

As you can see in the output there is a dropdown menu to show each plot separately. I found some information about [Tabsets section](https://quarto.org/docs/output-formats/html-basics.html) in `Quarto` and maybe thought that using `::: {.tabset-dropdown})` would do the job. I tried the following code in a `.tabset-dropdown`:

````
---
title: "Dropdown menu in Quarto"
format: html
---

::: {.tabset-dropdown}

## plot1

```{r}
plot(1:10, 1:10)
```

## plot2

```{r}
hist(rnorm(100))
```

:::
````

Output:

[image]

As you can see in the output, it didn't create a dropdown menu like in R Markdown. So I was wondering if it is possible to achieve the same in `Quarto`?

Comment: According to [this issue #419](https://github.com/quarto-dev/quarto-cli/issues/419) on Quarto Github repo, there's no such option right now, but they are considering adding this in the future.

Comment: @shafee, Thank you for your comment! Let's wait then for the future.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is what you are looking for, but you can create simply drop-downs for html documents by using:

```
<details>
<summary>dropdown_title</summary>
contents
</details>
```